# Issue with polymer theme

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I created a new polymer app using AppToolbox (polymer cli) and now I'm trying to add a theme that I download from [Polymer Theme](https://polymerthemes.com/denim/). I follow the instructions:
Add the following line inside your  tag
AFTER the webcomponents-lite.min.js and other HTML imports.

```
<link rel="import" href="path/to/theme.html">
```

To use the theme within your custom element, add the following line
inside your  tag:

```
<link rel="import" href="path/to/theme.css" type="css">
```

Of course I removed some css styles in the example components but I don't see the template applied to the project.

Could anyone give me some advice about this?

Instructions:
[image: Instructions Pic]

Comment: That looks weird `<link rel="import" href="path/to/theme.css" type="css">`. I would expect something like `<style include="theme-name"></style>`. Are you sure you're using the 1.0 usage instructions instead of 0.5?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure, you could see it in the link share in my question. Thanks

Comment: It requires an email address to be entered, that's where I closed the page.

Comment: I added the instructions picture.

Comment: Thanks. This still looks weird. As far as I know Polymer doesn't support importing `css` directly. It requires it to be inside a style module https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#style-modules

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer, I supposed I should disregard the instructions and do it in the way described in the documentation you shared with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** The only method that seems to allow those themes to work properly with Polymer 1.5.0 is to link the provided stylesheet in `index.html` with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/theme.css">
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/D7womzsmEtjJZQiJwVTD?p=preview)

---

The instructions from https://polymerthemes.com/ to import the CSS theme in your `<dom-module>` align with Polymer's [documentation on importing external stylesheets](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#external-stylesheets), but the support for that import-type is deprecated in favor of [style modules](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#style-modules).

However, even style modules don't allow full theming in my experiments.

*Trials:*

- Importing the provided theme in the `<dom-module>` ([deprecated](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#external-stylesheets)):

  ```
  <dom-module id="x-button">
    <link rel="import" type="css" href="theme.css"> <!-- partial styling -->
    ...
  </dom-module>
  ```

  **Result:** Styles are restricted to the custom element, but no font styling. [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gvka7W64OQmObxI3m9JH?p=preview)

  [image]
- Converting the provided theme into a style module, and including it in the `<dom-module>`:

  ```
  <link rel="import" href="theme.html">
  <dom-module id="x-button">
    <style is="custom-style" include="theme"></style>  <!-- partial styling -->
    ...
  </dom-module>
  ```

  **Result:** *(same effect as Trial 1)* [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YEgpO2zduS54nU6Lxjsu?p=preview)

  [image]
- Linking the provided stylesheet in `<dom-module>`:

  ```
  <dom-module id="x-button">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="theme.css">  <!-- full styling, leaks -->
    ...
  </dom-module>
  ```

  **Result:** `x-button` fully styled as intended, but styles leak into main page, modifying the background color and a `paper-button` of the main page. [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2UY6rsd4IvZH7syxZFX7?p=preview)

  [image]
- Linking the provided stylesheet only in `index.html`:

  ```
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="theme.css">  <!-- full styling -->
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <x-button></x-button>
  </body>
  ```

  **Result:** `x-button` fully styled as intended. [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/D7womzsmEtjJZQiJwVTD?p=preview)

  [image]

Comment: Excellent your explanation and thanks a lot for that, I really appreciate it.